# Can you bleed from your bones?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, human-physiology, bone-biology

I was talking to my science teacher about the body specifically the red bone marrow.

She said that blood is created in the red bone marrow. Does that mean that if you were to cut a fresh bone open it would bleed?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here? [Bone marrow is a solid spongy tissue](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/619_Red_and_Yellow_Bone_Marrow.jpg), and won't bleed.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' but don't harvasian canals have blood vessels and nerves?

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Yes. Harvesian canal. It ought to bleed right?

Comment: @Homosapien. I looked at the  make-up of a bone.

Comment: No one really knows where the term dry as bone came from, many assume it comes from sun bleached bone which was the easy way to dry bone for other uses.

Comment: I edited your question removing the last part of the question as it was unrelated to biology and the overall question. Feel free to rollback to your original question but I believe the edits will get you more upvotes for the attention you need to award the bounty. You could also add what you already know to the question to give answerers a starting point to go from

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, bones too bleed if they get damaged (break or bruise). This is because bones are highly vascularised organs and breaking of bones will indeed rupture the blood vessels causing bleeding. Main artery which supplies blood to bone is nutrient artery , others are epiphyseal, metaphyseal and periosteal arteries. Skeletal system receives about 15.6% of cardiac output.
Since bones contain very low percentage of water ( about 31% ) comapred to others like skin(64%),brain and heart (73%) and lungs ( 83%). So the saying "as dry as bone " stills holds well.

---

Sources:

1-https://www.mananatomy.com/basic-anatomy/blood-supply-bones

2-https://water.usgs.gov/edu/propertyyou.html

Comment: You can also have bone bruises, which I believe are the result of bleeding inside the bone.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It feels good to actually "know" people that will help me with questions. If you ever need anything tell me and I'll try to help.